# How can I change the color of fly/walk mode crosshair?

Tags: customization, theme

Is there any way we can change the color of the fly mode crosshair, this is the crosshair which is shown when in the new fps style fly mode (shift+f).

Currently the crosshair is black, I want a brighter color.

I have tried adjusting many theme parts but to no effect.
Is there a particular area to change the color or is this part not theme-able?

Comment: Not currently supported yet, I'm afraid. Nice point though.

Comment: If you *really*, ***really*** want to change it, you can probably change it in blender's source code and then compile it yourself. Other than that, I don't think it's possible atm.

Comment: Thanks to devs, it is now supported! See [here](https://developer.blender.org/D331) for details.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option is now supported, but not in time for version 2.70. Later versions will have this option and meanwhile you can [download a daily build](http://builder.blender.org/download/).

To change this setting go to: *User Preferences > Themes > 3D View* (on the left) and select *View Overlay*.

The option affects:
- the cursor (fly/walk and the default black part of the 3D cursor),
- the camera guides (enabled in *Camera Panel > Display*), and
- the stippled line guide that appears when scaling objects.