# Disabling Cross Hair

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'm trying to remove a cross hair that appears when I'm using the free roam camera view (SHIFT + tilda) perspective. I had already disabled the 3D cursor (cross hair) but this particular cross hair (as per image) is a different type. Any suggestions how to disable it ?[image: Cross Hair]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7981/128477 There is this answer for changing color, but unfortunately there is no Alpha channel value for that color, due to that you cannot make it transparent by default.... So maybe you need some addon that can make it

Comment: Thanks. I actually just want to be able to disable the cross hair completely like you can with the 3D Cursor. I guess it seems there is no disable feature in Blender at all.

Comment: Yes you cannot disable it by default nor you cannot change its color to transparent by default, so you need to find if there is another solution, that cross shares same value with 3d cursor (then I wonder why 3d cursor is disabled and this is not...)